# Copy cell content and paste it to another sheet multiple times

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy value from two specific cells to specific cells in another sheet.
Problem is that I have many cells in first sheet and some of them are empty. Also paste is always 99 times, just range changes. Is there a loop to make everything more easy?

Here is my attempt

```
Sub copytry()

Worksheets("sheetI").Range("I17:J17").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("sheetII").Range("F1352:F1451")
Worksheets("sheetI").Range("I18:J18").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("sheetII").Range("F1452:F151")

End Sub
```

Comment: *Is there a loop to make everything more easy?*  Yes. VBA has several loop or control flow statements. `For Each .. Next` or `For ... Next` would probably be useful, see [here](http://www.databison.com/vba-for-loop-for-next-and-for-each-in-next/) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Practice using this,

```
   Sub copytry()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet, lstrw As Long
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("sheetI")
    Set sh = Worksheets("sheetII")

    With ws

        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(17, "I"), .Cells(Rws, "I"))
        For Each c In Rng.Cells
            If c = "" Then c = "."    'Added to Code
            lstrw = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            c.Range("A1:B1").Copy Destination:=sh.Range(sh.Cells(lstrw, 1), sh.Cells(lstrw + 99, 1))

        Next c

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Your code is working and I have adapted it to my needs. It has only one thing that is missing: it is not copying and pasting empty cells on "sheetII". It should do that since that are values that are missing and i have to insert them manually. Can this code be upgraded to copy and paste also the missing values (empty cells)?

Comment: I have edited the code, if c="" then c=".", you can change it to a space if you want such as then c=" ", The code searches for the first empty cell in Column A SheetII, so that is why we need to replace the blank cells with something.